# How to put a verbatim section in place of teaser figure in acmart document?

Tags: xetex, verbatim, characters, acmart, figure-placement

I would like to use a graphic built from monospaced characters as a teaser figure in an acmart document. Elsewhere in the document I've used verbatim sections inside of table*s to do this, creating figures made of characters that span the width of the page. The acmart format makes it tough to place anything between the author line and the abstract, though, anything I try to put there is instead placed on its own page at the beginning of the document before anything else appears.

Looking at the acmart.cls class file, I see that the insertion of the teaser figure section is implemented with these lines:

```
\def\@teaserfigures{}
\newenvironment{teaserfigure}{\Collect@Body\@saveteaser}{}
\long\def\@saveteaser#1{\g@addto@macro\@teaserfigures{\@teaser{#1}}}
```

Is there a way to put arbitrary content like a verbatim into this area? There could be other options as well, like putting a verbatim at the end of the authors list somehow, as long as it appears between the authors list and main text. I'm using Xetex specifically.

Below is code for a sample acmart document containing a working teaser. Below the working teaserfigure spec is a commented spec expressing what I want: a teaserfigure with a verbatim inside it. Try commenting out the working teaser and enabling the one with the verbatim and you'll see that trying to generate it will fail.

The teaser for the code below depends on an image called "sampleteaser.pdf," part of ACM sample content available in the /samples folder inside this zip file: [ACM template file](https://portalparts.acm.org/hippo/latex_templates/acmart-primary.zip)

```
\documentclass[sigplan,screen]{acmart}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2023}
\acmYear{2023}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}

\acmConference[Conference]{Full Conference Name}{Date of}{Location}
\acmPrice{0.00}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{And a subtitle}

\author{Author Name}
\email{author@email.com}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keywords, go, here}

%% A "teaser" image appears between the author and affiliation
%% information and the body of the document, and typically spans the
%% page.

%% This teaser works:
\begin{teaserfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sampleteaser}
  \caption{Seattle Mariners at Spring Training, 2010.}
  \Description{Enjoying the baseball game from the third-base
  seats. Ichiro Suzuki preparing to bat.}
  \label{fig:teaser}
\end{teaserfigure}

%% This teaser is broken:
%% \begin{teaserfigure}
%%   \begin{verbatim}
%%     abc
%%     def
%%   \end{verbatim}
%% \end{teaserfigure}

%%
%% This command processes the author and affiliation and title
%% information and builds the first part of the formatted document.
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro goes here.

%% Here's a working verbatim as part of the article text:
\begin{verbatim}
  abc
  def
\end{verbatim}

\section{Conclusion}
Another section.

\end{document}
\endinput
```

A follow-up question: How can I apply styling to the fancy verbatim section? I'm trying this:

```
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{\maxdimen}
\setlength{\lineskip}{-0.1pt}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}[fontsize=6pt]{TeaserVerb}
  content
  goes
  here
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{teaserfigure}
\UseVerbatim{TeaserVerb}
\end{teaserfigure}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{1pt}
```

But it's not working. The lineskip changes are needed because I'm using box-drawing characters inside the section; there shouldn't be any lineskip so that there are no breaks between rows. I've also put a font size in there, I've also tried fontsize=small and that doesn't make a change either.

Comment: Welcome! Would you please add a small example, even if it doesn't work? Not everybody is acquainted with the details of `acmart`, in particular with `teaserfigure` and its placement.

Comment: It's been added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SaveVerbatim` from `fancyvrb`.

```
\documentclass[sigplan,screen]{acmart}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--- NOT with fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{setspace} % <--- ? Why?

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % <--- For SaveVerbatim

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2023}
\acmYear{2023}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}

\acmConference[Conference]{Full Conference Name}{Date of}{Location}
\acmPrice{0.00}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{And a subtitle}

\author{Author Name}
\email{author@email.com}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keywords, go, here}

%% A "teaser" image appears between the author and affiliation
%% information and the body of the document, and typically spans the
%% page.

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{TeaserVerb}
abc \LaTeX is {} nice
def
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{teaserfigure}
\UseVerbatim{TeaserVerb}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro goes here.

%% Here's a working verbatim as part of the article text:
\begin{verbatim}
  abc
  def
\end{verbatim}

\section{Conclusion}
Another section.

\end{document}
```

Don't load `inputenc` if you plan to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX (and `fontspec`). By the way `utf8` has been the default also for `pdflatex` for a few years.

I'd not load `setspace` with `acmart`.

Beware that verbatim modes respect initial spaces on lines, as shown in the example (see the `verbatim` in the body).

[image]

EDIT

How to do the special formatting? Here's a possible way, that keeps the setting of `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip` local.

```
\documentclass[sigplan,screen]{acmart}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--- NOT with fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{setspace} % <--- ? Why?

\usepackage{fancyvrb} % <--- For SaveVerbatim

\newsavebox{\verbteaserbox}

\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2023}
\acmYear{2023}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}

\acmConference[Conference]{Full Conference Name}{Date of}{Location}
\acmPrice{0.00}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{And a subtitle}

\author{Author Name}
\email{author@email.com}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keywords, go, here}

%% A "teaser" image appears between the author and affiliation
%% information and the body of the document, and typically spans the
%% page.

\setbox\verbteaserbox=\vbox{
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{\maxdimen}%
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\fontsize{6}{0}\selectfont
\begin{BVerbatim}
abc \LaTeX is {} nice
def
abc \LaTeX is {} nice
def
abc \LaTeX is {} nice
def
abc \LaTeX is {} nice
def
abc \LaTeX is {} nice
def
\end{BVerbatim}
}
\begin{teaserfigure}
\usebox{\verbteaserbox}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Intro goes here.

%% Here's a working verbatim as part of the article text:
\begin{verbatim}
  abc
  def
\end{verbatim}

\section{Conclusion}
Another section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works great. The verbatim section appears, but I'm now trying to style it without much luck. I've added some details to the question above, simply put I want to change the lineskip and lineskiplimit properties along with the font size inside the section but it's not working.

Comment: @phantomics Adding something more “real world” details would be better. I added a possible solution along what you asked for.

Comment: Excellent, that does the job. Now I have full control over the verbatim sections' formatting in the teaser area. Much appreciated.